# Trying to use variable in sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep, fastq

I have 2 separate text files, each in the same exact format. I can grep `FILE1.txt` for a specific search term and output the line numbers of every match. The line numbers are outputted in numeric order to a file or a variable.

I want use each line number and print that line from `FILE2.txt` in numeric order to a single `OUTPUT.txt`. Does anyone know a way, using `awk` or `sed` to do this?

I have a string variable $linenumbers with values of 25 26 27 28.

I use the following command:

> for i in $linenumbers; do sed -n "/$I/p" $i test_read2.fastq >> test.fastq; done.

I get errors of

sed: can't read 25: No such file or directory

sed: can't read 26: No such file or directory

sed: can't read 27: No such file or directory

sed: can't read 28: No such file or directory

If I do this sed command one by one, I can pull line number 25, 26, 27 and 28 from the file and print it to file using the following command;

> sed -n "25p" test_read2.fastq >> test.fastq

I want to replace "25p" with variable so it pulls out multiple lines (25,26,27,28) from the file without doing this one by one...

Comment: Please show us some code you have tried.

Comment: @user3406833,Give some inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep -n interesting FILE1.txt | cut -d: -f1 | while read l
do
   sed -n "$l p" FILE2.txt
done
```

Example:

```
$ cat FILE1.txt 
foo
bar
baz
$ cat FILE2.txt 
qux
quux
quuux
$ grep -n bar FILE1.txt | cut -d: -f1 | while read l; do sed -n "$l p" FILE2.txt; done
quux
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want to do. If you want to print the lines of `file` which are defined in `lines` you could do `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}FNR in a' lines file`

test:

```
$ cat lines
1
3
7
$ cat file
a
b
c
d
e
f
g

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}FNR in a' lines file
a
c
g
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I used your awk command with the following: > awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}FNR in a' $linenumbers test_read2.fastq. This give me an error: awk: cannot open 25 (no such fie or directory). This is odd because 25 is the line number I am trying to retrieve from test_read2.fastq file.

Comment: I assumed that the lines were stored in a file. If `$linenumbers` is variable holding the line numbers, then you should use process substitution instead:  `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}FNR in a' <(echo "$linenumbers") test_read2.fastq`

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! That did it!!! I also tried your first suggestion with a file and that worked too... you have ended my day long search for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n "` grep -n 'Yourpattern' File1.txt | sed 's/:.*/p/'`" File2.txt
```

be carefful with substitution and (double) quote in `YourPattern`